# Is it OK to tell a user to install mods/community patches to fix problems with old games?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

Not all of the games available on the internet can run on recent versions of Windows, and because of this, mods created by the community usually appear attempting to fix the problems that the game has and/or make it run on recent versions of operating systems.

Is OK to tell a user to install mods/community patches to fix problems with old games?

Some examples:

- [grand-theft-auto-san-andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-san-andreas) internal timings on missions like the [Dancing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255819/199843) and [Low Rider](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39907/199843) challenges can be fixed by installing [SilentPatch](https://gtaforums.com/topic/669045-silentpatch/)
- [the-simpsons-hit-and-run](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-simpsons-hit-and-run) does not allows the [use of non 4:3 resolutions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360154/199843), but this can be bypassed by using [Lucas' Simpsons Hit & Run Mod Launcher](https://donutteam.com/downloads/4/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Abso-lutely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMnT4tp-cMk). Mods are perfectly acceptable as an answer in pretty much every use case, and in situations like this, where they might be the *only* solution, they're all the more appropriate.